# How to give equal width for all the fields in the form with validations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, forms

In the below HTML5 form code, how to give equal width to all the names and input fields so that all the names are aligned in the same column and all the input type fields are aligned in same column with same width??

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>CSS Contact Form</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>

<body style=" background-color:#E5E4E2">

    <h2>Registration Form</h2>
    <div style="margin-left:420px; border:1px solid #ccc; width:400px; padding:15px; border-radius:5px;">
    <form class="form">

        <p class="name">
            <label for="name"> First Name *:</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="John" required/>
        </p>

        <p class="name">
            <label for="name">Last Name *:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Maxwell" required/>

        </p>

        <p class="web">
            <label for="web">Company Name *:</label>
            <input type="text" name="web" id="web" placeholder="BDI Systems & Technologies" required/>

        </p>

        <p class="email">
            <label for="email">Email Id *:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail@bdisys.com" required/>
        </p>

        <p class="budget">
            <label for="name">Budget :</label>
            <input type="text" name="budget" id="budget" placeholder="200000"/>

        </p>

        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </p>

    </form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Css:

```
body {
    padding: 100px 100px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #474E69;
    margin-left:420px;
}

/* ===========================
   ====== Contact Form ======= 
   =========================== */

input, textarea {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    width: 200px;
    color: #999999;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;     
}

textarea {
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    max-width: 400px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

input:hover, textarea:hover,
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    border-color: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 8px; 
}

.form label {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #999999;
}

/* ===========================
   ====== Submit Button ====== 
   =========================== */

.submit input {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #474E69; 
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;     
}
```

Comment: The simple and straightforward approach is to use tables

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb i Know that we can get it with tables very easily but i want to it to be done  with the same code as above.

Comment: Using Tables is an old approach. I won't recommend it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/sacaf/1/edit?html,css,output)

Just add display: inline-block and specify min-width to label element

```
.form label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #999999;
    min-width: 110px;
}
```

Comment: This is surely the best answer. Thumbs up.

Comment: Although the fields also need to be aligned right to make the formatting look cool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use floating to adjust the alignment. Like making the labels float left and fields float right.

I have created a fiddle for you with all changes. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/CZL4w/

I made the following changes in CSS:

```
input, textarea {
   float:right;
}
input, textarea {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    width: 200px;
    color: #999999;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;     
   float:right;
}
.form label {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #999999;
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

And the following changes in your HTML code:

```
<div style="margin-left:420px; border:1px solid #ccc; width:400px; padding:15px; border-radius:5px; float:left;">
```

I hope this helps.